# How to open all files that are dragged and dropped on application icon?

Tags: delphi, file-io, drag-and-drop, multiple-instances

I know how to open ONE file in this way and how to get number of files which are dragged and dropped on EXE or shortcut for my application.

But, how to run multiple instances of application, one for each file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd put this at the start of my .dpr file's code:

```
if ParamCount>1 then
begin
  for i := 1 to ParamCount do
    ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(ParamStr(0)), PChar('"'+ParamStr(i)+'"'), 
        nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
  exit;
end;
```

This checks to see if there is more than a single command line argument. If so, then each one is handed off to a new process, and this process terminates.

I suppose you could hand off arguments 2 to N and let this process handle argument 1. But, being of a mathematical nature, the symmetry of this version appeals to me.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use the current instance for one of the files?

Comment: Fair enough. I also thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the droppend files are passed as parameters, an new instance of the Application can be run for every parameter passed.
In the example shown below, the first Parameter will be handled by the Application started via Drog&Drop in the explorer, an new instance of the Application will be run for any additional parameter.

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms, Shellapi,Messages,Windows,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}
var
i:Integer;
begin
  for I := 2 to Paramcount  do
      ShellExecute(0,'OPEN',PChar(Paramstr(0)),PChar(Paramstr(i)),'',sw_Show);
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Simplest example for Code in Form2 could by

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := ParamStr(1); 
  // whatever should be done with the dropped file
end;
```

Comment: What is this code meant to demonstrate? Write some *sentences* explaining the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each file dropped on your app icon or shortcut will be a command-line parameter. You can loop through them easily:

```
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to ParamCount do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ParamStr(i));
end;
```

So for each, you can open a separate form within your app (e.g. from within your main form's OnCreate), or you could also code this in a routine called from the project (.dpr) file prior to it's normal startup code and launch additional instances of your app for each (saving one for the instance you are doing this from).

E.g. in the loop above you could use ShellExecute or CreateProcess to start instances of yourself passing ParamStr(i) as that instances single parameter.